# Image is not loading from ImageField

Tags: python, django

My images are getting properly saved in media folder(/media/appIcons/). I am loading image using below html code

```
<img class="card-img" src="{{ app.image.url}}">
```

But it is not loading on page and i am not seeing any error on console.

I have all settings in place.

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media/")
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

When i inspected elements on browser path is coming properly

```
<img class="card-img" src="/media/appIcons/test.png">
```

Any help is much appreciated.

PS python 2.7, Django 1.11

Comment: whats the response status for the image? 200 or 404? and make sure any CSS is not hiding the image.

Comment: response code 200.  CSS is working fine with static page

Comment: Response
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 25 Jan 2020 17:06:00 GMT
Content-Length: 2147
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.16